# How to access value of column from one table in trigger of another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Created Star Schema where Sales is a fact table and Product_Dimension is one of the dimension tables.
Created Product_Dimension table

```
    Create Table Product_Dimension
    (Product_ID char(6),
    Product_Name varchar(20),
    Product_Category varchar(10),
    Unit_Price decimal(6,2));

    alter table Product_Dimension add constraint pk_Product_Dimension 
    Primary key(Product_ID);
```

Created Fact table-sales

```
    Create table Sales(
    Product_ID char(5),Order_ID char(5),Customer_ID char(6),Employer_ID 
    char(5),total int, Quantity int, Discount decimal(5,2),
    foreign key (Product_ID) references Product_Dimension(Product_ID),
    foreign key (Order_ID) references Time_Dimension(Order_id),
    foreign key (Customer_ID) references Customer_Dimension(Customer_ID),
    foreign key (Employer_ID) references Emp_Dimension(Emp_ID)
    );
```

I want to create a trigger which calculates value of Total from values of Quantity and Discount from Sales table and Unit_Price from Product_Dimension table.

**So every time we insert value in Sales, it should take Quantity(taken from insert query we trying to replace) multiply it with Unit_Price from Product_Dimension table where Product_IDs are matching and subtract Discount(taken from insert query)**

Sales_view is a view of Sales table

```
    CREATE or replace TRIGGER Update_Total
    instead of insert on Sales_view for each row

    declare
    y decimal(6,2);
    x decimal(6,2);
    begin

    x:=select pd.Unit_Price from Product_Dimension where 
    pd.Product_ID=:NEW.Product_ID;
    y:=(:NEW.Quantity*x)-:NEW.Discount

    insert into  
    Sales_view(Product_ID,Order_ID,Customer_ID,Employer_ID,total, 
    Quantity, 
    Discount)
    values(:NEW.Product_ID,:NEW.Order_ID,:NEW.Customer_ID,:NEW.Employer 
    y,:NEW.Quantity,:NEW.Discount);
  
    end;
```

This gives following errors in oracle-live sql:

```
    Errors: TRIGGER UPDATE_TOTAL
    Line/Col: 6/4 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when 
    expecting one of the following:

    ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
    date <a string literal with character set specification>
    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set 
    specification>
    <an alternat
    Line/Col: 7/1 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "Y" 
    Line/Col: 7/35 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting 
    one 
    of the following:

    . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
    like4 likec between || indicator member submultiset

    Line/Col: 12/4 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when 
    expecting one of the following:

    end not pragma final instantiable persistable order
    overriding static member constructor map
```

Comment: Where - in Oracle documentation - did you find such a syntax? That does **NOT** look like Oracle.

Comment: It's PL/SQL rather than a plain SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Your Trigger syntax is wrong. The correct syntax should look alike -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Update_Total
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Sales_view
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    y decimal(6,2);
    x decimal(6,2);
BEGIN

    SELECT pd.Unit_Price
      INTO x
      FROM Product_Dimension
     WHERE pd.Product_ID=:NEW.Product_ID;
    
    y := (:NEW.Quantity*x) - :NEW.Discount;

    INSERT INTO Sales_view (Product_ID, Order_ID, Customer_ID, Employer_ID,
                            total, Quantity, Discount)
                    VALUES (:NEW.Product_ID, :NEW.Order_ID, :NEW.Customer_ID, :NEW.Employer,
                            y,:NEW.Quantity,:NEW.Discount);
  
END;
```

Comment: Trigger was created but when I try to insert using insert into Sales_view(Product_ID,Order_ID,Customer_ID,Employer_ID,Quantity,Discount) values ('2j1ojp','21875','171912','19dn2',1,0.00); It gives the following error: ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded ORA-06512: at "SQL_YCPCFMGEKANWAJIINYQDFVBDR.UPDATE_TOTAL", line 6
ORA-06512: at "SQL_YCPCFMGEKANWAJIINYQDFVBDR.UPDATE_TOTAL", line 13
ORA-06512: at "SQL_YCPCFMGEKANWAJIINYQDFVBDR.UPDATE_TOTAL", line 13

Comment: You are getting this error because when you are issuing an Insert statement this trigger invokes, which itself uses an insert statement to invoke the trigger again. So this trigger is getting invoked recursively. You need to fix your logic to overcome this issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to load data into your star schema using triggers? This seems like a really bad approach